# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'sortObject' was corrupted. how to fix?

Tags: c++

I was trying to store numbers in an array. The first half of the array are numbers that are ascending 1,2,3,4,5 etc and the second half of the array are random numbers. When i run the program it produces the output I wanted but gives me the error please help

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 using namespace std;

 class sorting {
 private:
int size, elements;
int arr[NULL];


public:
void sort(){
    cout << "Enter number of desired elements" << ">"; cin >> elements;
    arr[elements];
    half();
    

}
void half() {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements/2; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for (int i = elements / 2; i < elements; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
    cout << "This is the elements of the array";
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
};
   int main()
{
sorting sortObject;

sortObject.sort();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int arr[NULL];` you declared  arr to have no elements. You can't change that later on. It's a compile time constant. My advice is to use a `std::vector` instead which is the c++ dynamic array.

Comment: Ok imma try to change it

Comment: @drescherjm Please create an answer or propose a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i could see you want the array size to change during run time depending on the input, we need to dynamically allocate a array.so take a integer pointer as a field instead of static array.
then inside the sort function after reading the input, dynamically allocate the memory to pointer.(actually its better if we do it in a constructor).

```
int *arr;
arr=(int *)malloc(elements*sizeof(int));
```